# Postgres-XC and MPP

Tags: postgres-xc

I'm currently considering using Postgres-XC or Postgres-XL to create a long term data store for around 20 TB of data or more.

I read the information in Postgres-XL website that Postgres-XC is not yet an MPP architecture. But, I can see that it is already has a "Coordinator" that acts as master node and a bunch of data nodes that do not shares data (shared-nothing).

What makes Postgres-XC not an MPP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am one of the original developers of both projects.

They both have a Coordinator and Datanodes, that is true. The Coordinator plans and directs execution on both as well.

Perhaps a few examples will help.

Let's say you have three tables, `t1`, `t2` and `r1`. `t1` has columns `a1` and `a2`, and `t2` has columns `b1` and `b2`. `t1` is distributed (sharded) on `a1`, and `t2` is distributed on `b1`. `r1` has columns `c1` and `c2` and is replicated, with an exact copy of each row

For simple queries like `SELECT * FROM t1`, it will be parallelized in both Postgres-XC and Postgres-XL.

Another example:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN r1 ON t1.a1 = r1.c1
```

will also be parallelized in both, with the join being "pushed down" to the data nodes. We can do this because `r1` is replicated on each node. This type of query is fine where `t1` is a big fact table and `r1` is a dimension table.

Let's look at a different case:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.a1 = t2.b2
```

Here we are joining on the distribution column of `t1`, but NOT on the distribution column of `b2`. In a 4 node cluster, a row on node1 in `t1` could potentially need to be joined with rows in `t2` on node1, node2, node3 and node4.

Postgres-XC handles this by shipping all of the data that qualifies in the join from each table to the Coordinator, and joins there. In the example, we did not include any `WHERE` clause qualifiers. So, it will ship the entire contents of t1 and t2 from node1, node2, node3 and node4 over to the Coordinator, and then join there. There would be no join parallelism, and you also have the overhead of shipping all of the data to one place. So in this case, Postgres-XC would actually be slower than native PostgreSQL, much slower if the tables are large.

Postgres-XL would handle this differently. Remember the join condition is `t1.a1 = t2.b2`. It would recognize that `b2` is being equijoined `a1`, which is the distribution column of `t1`. That is, if we have the `b2` value, we know exactly on which node the data it needs to join with in `t1` resides (since we can apply the hash distribution function on the value).  As data is produced on each node for `t2`, it will be consumed by exactly the one datanode that needs it for `t1`, and do so directly without going through the coordinator.

The datanodes are simultaneously reading from `t1` and producing `t2` rows for joining with `t1`, having the data from `t2` directly consumed by the datanode that needs it for a particular row.

This direct datanode-to-datanode communication allows for more parallelization for more complicated queries compared to Postgres-XC.

I hope that helps to answer your question.

Postgres-XL also has other performance improvements. Sequences are handled more optimally for one.

Comment: Ok, so, it means that the advantage of Postgres-XL is in its datanode-to-datanode communication? If I may know, how mature Postgres-XL is compared to Postgres-XC? Since, I think the project has just started this year. Thanks.